# SQL Query of Closed Excel Workbook Returns NULL When Workbook is Closed

Tags: sql, excel, vba, null, adodb

Edit: Sample of Data I am querying is below. The Data I am most concerned about is in range Q40:AV300

[View of Data When Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tejTY.png)

Note cell reference in formula bar for selected cell. I am not sure if this has any impact on the query.
[Workbook view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyoQn.png)

I have an Excel .Xlsx workbook that I am trying to query through VBA to get data from while it is closed. I connect to the closed workbook by ADODB Connection. If I run the code while the workbook is closed I get NULL for all the values returned. If I run the same code while it is open it returns all the values as expected. If I copy all cells and pastevalues in the workbook then I can read while it is closed. Writing a script to open the workbook and do this would take longer than I would like and could otherwise just read the data from the open workbook.

The workbook is not setup in a table format so I have been referencing the column number by [F1] to [Fn] when I look at specific columns. I can target the correct columns and get the filtered data when the workbook is open. This does not seem to be the problem. Also the data is intermixed with blank cells and the cell values I am looking for. Again, this does not seem to be a problem when the workbook is open. Rows 1-39 are mostly blank. I have tried limiting the rows it searches so the first value is not a NULL value. The data in columns 1-24/"A:X" are mostly formula references to other columns. I.e. `=Y24`. I have tried looking at just columns which have only string or numeric values intermixed with blank cells. I still get null values from every returned value. The columns with strings only have strings and blank cells. The columns with numeric values only have numeric values or blank cells.

I read somewhere else that in the query it looks for most common data type in the queried region. It is possible that there are more blank cells in a column than cells with values. Could it be that the query is automatically assigning a null type since it is the most common data? If so, is there a way to tell the query what data type I expect in the column?

Sample SQL String: `CommandText = "Select * From [BV_284700$y40:y300]"`

Again, this filters the range while the workbook is open, but appears to do nothing while the workbook is closed. All the results return NULL.

I have checked that the connection is established by using `connection.state` which displays the connection is established.

I can pull the data by opening the workbook and getting that way, but it is obviously slower to do in this method. Also if I copy and paste values in the workbook I can read the data through the query while the workbook is closed. I could write a script to open and paste values in each workbook, but this would make the overall VBA script about as slow as just opening the workbooks and getting the values. When I open the workbooks and read directly it takes about 40s for code to run. With the query it takes about 3.5s. Ultimately I am trying to write the values to a worksheet cell range or an array. I have gotten this to work when the query returns the expected results.

Below is my code section of the query portion of my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub ADOexample()
    
    Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    'Worksheet name is BV_284700
    CommandText = "Select * From [BV_284700$y40:y300]"
    
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
            " fileName & _
            ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; imex=1;hdr=no"";"
                      
    conn.Open ConnectionString
 
    Set rs = conn.Execute(CommandText)
    
    rscount = 0
    'This just loops through to see if there are values which are not null in a given field
    
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        
        Do While IsNull(rs.Fields(0).Value)
            rs.MoveNext
            rscount = rscount + 1
        Loop
        
    Loop
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.ClearContents
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sometimes, a screenshot of how your data looks like it is better that all the description you made. It is hard to follow it.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a snapshot of what the data looks like. Its hard to display in a screenshot because the data is so dispersed. This is the way the workbook comes to me and I am trying to automate processing the file for the data I need.

Comment: Just wondering why you are using an ADODB Connection to read the 2nd workbook especially when the data is not set up as a table?

Comment: It’s faster to read the data than it is to open each workbook. I have 6 workbooks for different departments that are each set up in this manner. I am trying to collect the information that meets a specific criteria. 

Is there a better alternative to use?

Comment: You might be right but I’d be surprised if you’re method is significantly faster than opening the workbooks in read-only mode. Given that your data is not structured as tables I would have thought the benefits of not having to treat it as dummy tables would outweigh any performance gain from accessing it as tables

Comment: Is there another method to open the workbook in read only mode. I am currently using workbooks.open(path) with screen updating turned off.